# What is the difference between <%= %> syntax and <%# %> in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between <%= %> syntax and <%# %> in asp.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete reference for all of these "inline tags," with links to MSDN for each type:
http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx

Answer (score 0):

<%= %> is basically used for string while <%# %> is used for data binding.
See following
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860

Answer (score 0):

As compared to the <%= version, <%# is treated specially in parameters. It adds a data binding handler and sets the property at data bind time. That's why <%# does work in parameters and why it picks up the value at data bind time.